# Multiple image patterns in 2d context of HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am having difficulties rendering several patterns (each with different texture) in the 2d context of HTML5 canvas.

Assuming I have three separate canvases, two off-screen containing different textures and one for rendering. Let these offline canvases be A and B.

Then:

```
var patternA = ctx.createPattern(A, "repeat-x");
ctx.fillStyle = patternA;
ctx.fillRect(100,100,20,20);

var patternB = ctx.createPattern(B, "repeat-y");
ctx.fillStyle = patternB;
ctx.fillRect(150,100,20,20);
```

There should be two 20x20 rectangles, each with their own pattern, however the second rectangle doesn't render at all. I've tried everything to get them working, but to no avail.

Why is that? How should I render multiple tiling textures onto the same canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What browsers are you trying?  With FireFox and Chrome, I couldn't get either pattern to render with `repeat-x` or `repeat-y`.  Instead, I was able to get both to render with just `repeat`. (See http://jsfiddle.net/ZthsS/1/)

It is possible that browsers have an incomplete implementation of the specification.  According to the implementation status at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-createpattern, IE beta and FF nightly pass all test cases but other browsers don't.  I would recommend just using `repeat` for the time being.  You could emulate `repeat-x` and `repeat-y` by simply limiting the width of the fillRect to the width of the pattern:

```
var patternA = ctx.createPattern(A, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = patternA;
ctx.fillRect(100,100,20,Math.min(20, A.height));

var patternB = ctx.createPattern(B, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = patternB;
ctx.fillRect(150,100,Math.min(20, B.width), 20);
```

Comment: Looks like that was the case. Guess I'll have to use repeat for now. Thanks!